# Errors with Agricolae Package in R when running AMMI model: "Error in model.frame.default : variable lengths differ

Tags: r, package

I keep getting this error message while trying to run my AMMI model with Agricolae:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Y ~ ENV + GEN, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : variable lengths differ (found for 'ENV')
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
str(data1)
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  4 variables:
$ ENV: Factor w/ 6 levels "E1","E2 ","E3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
$ GEN: Factor w/ 10 levels "G1","G10","G2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 ...
$ YLD: num  997 791 698 673 793 ...
$ pH : num  5.8 6.8 7 5.9 6.9 5.7 5.8 6.8 7 5.9 ...
```

I use this code for the model:

```
model <- with(data1, AMMI(ENV, GEN, REP = NULL, Y = c(YLD,pH), console=FALSE))
```

Please help

Comment: The error comes from the fact you are concatenating Y with YLD and pH which produces Y of length 120 while the other variables are of length 60. What is your desired Y ?

Comment: The Y is supposed to be the response variables, - in this case these are the yield and the pH.

Comment: Then I think you will have to do 2 separate analysis `model <- with(data1, AMMI(ENV, GEN, REP, Y = YLD, console=FALSE))`
`model <- with(data1, AMMI(ENV, GEN, REP, Y = pH, console=FALSE))`

Comment: I cannot specify a factor for the replication as my data comprises of just the genotype by environment means. I get "Error in AMMI(ENV, GEN, REP, Y = YLD, console = FALSE) :  object 'REP' not found" if I omit REP. If I specify that REP = NULL in this case, as in "model <- with(data1, AMMI(ENV, GEN, REP=NULL, Y = YLD, console=FALSE))" then I get an error message: Error in xx[2, 1] <- DFEa : replacement has length zero